# jQuery find() function is returning different kind of results on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a header bar with a search function on my site.
One of the functions I've implemented involves finding results and resizing the boxes that contain them.

One one page that has this header bar my function works perfectly:

```
$(".suggestionCategory").each(function() {
        $(this).find(".suggestionCategoryName").outerHeight($(this).find(".suggestionCategoryValues").height());
});
```

But on another I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined

Upon breaking and inspecting I can see the result of

```
$(this).find(".suggestionCategoryValues")
```

returns very different things.  On the page that functions correctly:

```
$(this).find(".suggestionCategoryValues")
```

evaluates to:

```
[
<div class=​"suggestionCategoryValues">​…​</div>​
]
```

But on the page where it fails it evaluates to:

```
[
b.fn.b.init[1]
  0: div.suggestionCategoryValues
  context: div.suggestionCategoryValues
  length: 1
  __proto__: Object[0]
]
```

Why is this and what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

First off - I don't want to know how to fix it - I've already got a workaround (do an inner foreach and total up the sizes of $(".suggestionCategoryValues").height().

But I'm curious as to why they are different.

The HTML is identical I believe but I will post the markup just in case I'm being an idiot.
This is the markup for the "broken" page:

```
<div id="searchSuggestionSelection" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 3.9em; left: 324px; height: 343px;">
    <div class="suggestionCategory">
        <div class="suggestionCategoryName"><span>company</span></div>
        <div class="suggestionCategoryValues">
             <div data-actual-search="XXXX" class="suggestionValue first">XXXX</div>
             <div data-actual-search="YYYY" class="suggestionValue">YYYY</div>
             <div data-actual-search="ZZZZ" class="suggestionValue">ZZZZ</div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="suggestionCategory">
         <div class="suggestionCategoryName"><span>contact</span></div>
         <div class="suggestionCategoryValues">
             <div data-actual-search="AAAA" class="suggestionValue first">AAAA</div>
             <div data-actual-search="BBBB" class="suggestionValue">BBBB</div>
             <div data-actual-search="CCCC" class="suggestionValue">CCCC</div>
             <div data-actual-search="DDDD" class="suggestionValue">DDDD</div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And this is the markup for the "working" page:

```
<div id="searchSuggestionSelection" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 3.9em; left: 324px; height: 823px;">
    <div class="suggestionCategory">
        <div class="suggestionCategoryName" style="height: 316px;"><span>company</span></div>
        <div class="suggestionCategoryValues">
            <div data-actual-search="XXXX" class="suggestionValue first">XXXX</div>
            <div data-actual-search="YYYY" class="suggestionValue">YYYY</div>
            <div data-actual-search="ZZZZ" class="suggestionValue">ZZZZ</div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="suggestionCategory">
         <div class="suggestionCategoryName" style="height: 512px;"><span>contact</span></div>
         <div class="suggestionCategoryValues">
             <div data-actual-search="AAAA" class="suggestionValue first">AAAA</div>
             <div data-actual-search="BBBB" class="suggestionValue">BBBB</div>
             <div data-actual-search="CCCC" class="suggestionValue">CCCC</div>
             <div data-actual-search="DDDD" class="suggestionValue">DDDD</div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

As you can see the "working" page successfully gets heights applied.

Comment: What is `this` in both instances?

Comment: It's the result of an iteratino of each(function(){}) - I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: Are you running them both on `ready` ?

Comment: This looks pretty dangerous: $(".suggestionCategory").find... I would rewrite it $('#TheHeaderBarID').find('.suggestionCategory').... using the ID of the level container, just in case you have  other suggestionCategory elements elsewhere on the page.

Comment: No they are triggered by an event (Or one of a few events actually)

Comment: Can you try to show us what is "this" for your two this ? I can't figure what it is. First one should be your "suggestionCategory" currently used in your each(), but the second one ... i guess it is the collection of "suggestionCattegoryName", Am I right ? and is that what you wanted ?

Comment: are you trying to assign the `height` of one child to `outerheight` of another child of the same parent???

Comment: @Okazari $(this) is the same in all cases, specifically a div with the class .suggestionCategory:  [
<div class=​"suggestionCategory">​
<div class=​"suggestionCategoryName">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"suggestionCategoryValues">​…​</div>​
</div>​
]

Comment: @rps Yes that's exactly what I'm doing.  Making both children the same height, specifically the .suggestionCategoryName the same height as .suggestionCategoryValues

Comment: okay, so basically in your other page one of the child `$(".suggestionCategoryValues")` seems to be undefined, you are sharing same script between pages? and I know you must have already checked but still you sure there is an element with `class='suggestionCategoryValues'` that is a child of _suggestionCategory_ in your other page? can you post the html code too sir?

Comment: @frenchie Nope it's not dangerous - first of all I'm in complete control of the markup, secondly I'm fine with applying this to any element that matches my hierarchy of classes. If extra elements appeared with those classes, they should have the same treatment - they are the same class after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow - that was a lot of effort for something so trivial.
On the "broken" page I was also including something called moorainbow.  A colour picker that works with mooTools.  The version I was including was about 7 years old, and for some reason it was interfering with jQuery in a hideously hard to detect way.

Possibly putting jQuery into no-conflict mode might have solved it, which is probably best practice anyway, but would have involved a fair amount of re-factoring of $'s into jQuery's. So instead I just removed the mooRainbow from the page and voila - problem solved, both pages act identically again.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because "this" is something else than you have expected, try storing it in a variable (called category) like this:

```
$(".suggestionCategory").each(function() {
  var category = $(this);       
  var height = category.find(".suggestionCategoryValues").height();
  category.find(".suggestionCategoryName").outerHeight(height);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing some testing I'm not sure why you would do

`.find(".suggestionCategoryName").outerHeight($(this).find(".suggestionCategoryValues").height());`

When I did my testing the parameter in the outerHeight is the same as if you set it to `outerHeight(true);`

```
$(".suggestionCategory").each(function() {
  var category = $(this);       
  category.find(".suggestionCategoryName").outerHeight(true);
 });
```

//other method

```
var suggestCat = $('.suggestionCategory'),i;
for(i=0;i<suggestCat.length;i++){
   var indexCat = suggestCat[i];
   $(indexCat).find('.suggestionCategoryName').outerHeight(true);
   }
```

Also if you are trying to set the height of an element wouldn't it be easier to use the height function?

```
var suggestCat = $('.suggestionCategory'),i;
for(i=0;i<suggestCat.length;i++){
   var indexCat = suggestCat[i];
   $(indexCat).height(function(ele,index){
     return this.find('.suggestionCategoryName').height();
    });
   }
```

As I am very unsure what the issue is perhaps or read your post wrong I could be providing it the wrong answers. You can also add an if statement to check if the element exist first.

Comment: I need to set the outerHeight of the suggestionCategoryname element, because of padding and margins.  Please see my edit about why I'm not looking for a fix, but an explanation.

Comment: @MattFellows it may seem that that `.suggestionCategoryValues` may not exist in other pages. Could you try doing `.suggestionValue` or is that also not what you are looking for. Just trying to figure out the issue of being undefined on another page.

Comment: As I've stated in my edit to the question - the (relevant?) markup is identical.  By relevant I mean the markup that I'm referencing with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".suggestionCategory").each(function() {
  var suggestionCategory = $(this);       
  suggestionCategory.find(".suggestionCategoryName").outerHeight(suggestionCategory.find(".suggestionCategoryValues").height());
});
```

Comment: On the "broken" page I get: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined